# Sending image from android to php server

Tags: php, android, image, upload

I have a great problem with this piece of code. My goal is to send an image (stored in my sd card) to my server via php. Here's the code. I've also used these 4 libs

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.Base64;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams; 



public void mytry(){

String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myImage.png";
String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
params.put("filename", fileName);
if (imgPath != null && !imgPath.isEmpty()) {
     encodeImagetoString();
}
     else {
         Log.v("NO","no File");
     }
}

public void encodeImagetoString() {
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    };

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 3;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,
                options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream); 
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        Log.v("OK","Calling Upload");
        // Put converted Image string into Async Http Post param
        params.put("image", encodedString);
        // Trigger Image upload
        triggerImageUpload();
    }
}.execute(null, null, null);
}

public void triggerImageUpload() {
    makeHTTPCall();
}

public void makeHTTPCall() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.post("http://mywebsite.com/phppage.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e)  {
                Log.v("Fail","Epic fail");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // When Http response code is '404'
                if (statusCode == 404) {
                   Log.v("NO","Requested resource not found");

                }
                // When Http response code is '500'
                else if (statusCode == 500) {
                     Log.v("NO","Something went wrong at server end");
                }
                // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                else {

                     Log.v("NO","Error Occured \n Most Common Error: \n1. Device not connected to Internet\n2. Web App is not deployed in App server\n3. App server is not running\n HTTP Status code : "
                                    + String.valueOf(statusCode));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response)  {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Hide Progress Dialog
                Log.v("Yeah",String.valueOf(statusCode));
                Log.v("Yeah",String.valueOf(headers));
                Log.v("Yeah",String.valueOf(response));
            }


        });
}
```

And here it is the php code:

```
<?php

$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];


$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: image/png; charset=utf-8');

$file = fopen("uploads/".$filename, 'wb');


fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);

?>
```

When I run my app I get "Success" (response 200 and so on) but my php page looks like it did receive anything. I've been spending two days on this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it creates a file in `uploads/`?

Comment: No.
When I stringify "params" I get filename followed by the name and image followed by a sequence of letters and numbers, but it looks like the php file can't even read the $_REQUEST['filename'] part

Comment: Let the php script echo the filename to begin with. And check response. Check the amount of bytes in image. Compare to the amount sent. Just do some basic debugging first.